# Merge from arcpy.ListTables() producing duplicate rows?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, merge

I was trying to manually merge file geodatabase tables and was getting Null values for the output file rows and decided to write a python script to merge the files. Here's my script: import arcpy

```
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "G:/US county_Climate Hazard models/NWS_County/SUMCounty_NWS_new_frq.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
tableList = arcpy.ListTables()
arcpy.Merge_management(tableList, "C:/Documents/ArcGIS/Default.gdb/Merge_sum_freq")
```

The code takes some time to run but runs without errors. However, when I open ArcMap back again and check for the output, I get duplicate entries in the table I made. Here's how the output looks like:

[image]

As you see every entry is duplicated. Could someone explain why is that the case and how could I fix it? Is there something going on with the way I wrote the code?

****EDIT # 1******
I also added:

```
print tableList
```

and I got:

```
[u'CT_09001', u'CT_09003', u'CT_09005', u'Merge_sum_freq']
```

(I'm not sure why I get this "u" thing)

****EDIT #2*****
The original question is now resolved thanks to Michael Miles-Stimson. I accidentally created Merge_sum_freq inside of SUMCounty_NWS_new_frq.gdb

****EDIT #3 NEW Question *****
I have a performance related question: every geodatabase table I need to merge has 1 row and 6 fields (including OBJECTID), which you could see on the screenshot I posted. When I run the above script for 10 tables, it runs in 10sec. For 30 tables - 8sec, 264 tables - ~2min. In the end I need to merge >3000 tables (every table with 1 row, so final table will have >3000 rows). Not sure if I'm extrapolating this right, but it seems like they would complete in >20min. Is this considered a good performance? If not, is there any way I could optimize anything?

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS.SE. What's the contents of the original tables? Are there two tables with the same values?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Thank you! originally there were 3 tables, each having one row only. So after merging there should have been just 3 rows with CT_09001, CT_09003, CT_09005. Instead, I got 6 rows.

Comment: Try printing your tableList variable to see if it had the value you expect, and edit that result into your Question.

Comment: I think you should reward @MichaelMiles-Stimson by upvoting his Answer, rather than just Accept-ing it, then research/ask your performance/optimization question, separately.

Comment: @PolyGeo I really tried, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to do that. I need at least 15 and I have just 8.

Comment: Sorry - I always forget that - anyway you should now have 5 more points of reputation - it was great seeing you work with @MichaelMiles-Stimson to clarify and resolve your Question.

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo! I'll keep that in mind and will come back and upvote @MichaelMiles-Stimson once I have enough reputation. Since you have a lot of experience in this community: should I ask my optimization question as a separate question on edit is fine?

Comment: I think such a Merge should only take a few seconds (on top of importing arcpy which may be 30 secs for first time) so the performance you describe does not sound right.  In a new Question make sure you describe things like how many rows, how many fields, in each of your 3 then 3,000 tables, and how long it takes for say 3, 10, 30, 100 tables to enable extrapolation into what you may be looking at for 3,000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# two traps here for beginners, well spotted!
env.workspace = "G:/US county_Climate Hazard models/NWS_County/SUMCounty_NWS_new_frq.gdb"
env.overwriteOutput = True

outTable = "C:/Documents/ArcGIS/Default.gdb/Merge_sum_freq"

# Clear the way, just to be sure
if arcpy.Exists(outTable):
    try:
        arcpy.Delete_management(outTable)
    except:
        import sys
        arcpy.AddError("Unable to delete table, may be locked!")
        sys.exit(-1) # exit here, unable to complete

inTables = arcpy.ListTables()

# report the tables, check here for duplicates
for Tbl in inTables:
    arcpy.AddMessage("Table : " + Tbl)

arcpy.Merge_management(inTables,outTable)
```

Have a look at your messages; I have used AddMessage and AddError as I don't know if you're using the toolbox or command line environment, these reporting tools work with both. If you see the table names more than once each there's a problem with listtables (unlikely)... most likely the script was unable to remove the previous table and has appended instead.

Comment: Thanks! I did everything you said and the messages I got:
Table : CT_09001
Table : CT_09003
Table : CT_09005
Table : Merge_sum_freq
However, I still get the same output as before ;(

Comment: Is there a Merge_sum_freq table in your NWS_County/SUMCounty_NWS_new_frq.gdb database?

Comment: ahhh thanks, there was, apparently when I was playing around with code I accidentally created one inside!

Comment: That explains it!