# Writing multiple file geodatabase tables into csv file with arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, python-2.7, merge

I was asking a question about Merging geodatabase previously, (link: [Merge from arcpy.ListTables() producing duplicate rows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101919/merge-from-arcpy-listtables-producing-duplicate-rows)) and although the script worked, it took more than 9 hours to run when merging >3000 tables with 1 rows in each table. I was wondering whether instead of merging the tables it would be faster to write the contents of each geodatabase table into a csv file and keep appending tables to it. If so, how to do it?? I now need to merge tables of different geodatabase (it has 39 fields and varying number of rows) and I have a feeling that if I use the script from my previous question it will take even longer than 9 hours.

Basically, how to iterate through 3000 tables and write the attribute tables of each to the same csv and keep appending to it?

Here's the screenshot of the geodatabase tables I talked about above:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With cursors and the `csv` module, this should go pretty quick:

```py
import arcpy, csv, time

arcpy.env.workspace = <path to gdb>
table_list = arcpy.ListTables()

csv_out = <path to csv>

#Get name of fields from first entry
fields = [x.name for x in arcpy.ListFields(table_list[0])]   

start = time.time()
counter = 0

with open(csv_out, "wb") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerow(fields)
    for table in table_list:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, fields) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                counter += 1
                wr.writerow(row)

end = time.time()- start

print "{0} rows from {1} tables written in {2} seconds".format(counter, len(table_list), end)
```

On my machine, this was the output from tables with 26 fields:

> 3636 rows from 101 tables written in 7.33599996567 seconds.

Comment: thanks so much! I no longer have access to computer arcgis and these data, but I'll try your suggestion tomorrow. would that be okay with you if I ask you again IFF something is not going to work as expected?

Comment: @atoregozh, sure! I updated the script a bit to show the run time. Should eat through 3000 tables in no time.

Comment: thanks again! how do get 101 pseudo tables with 26 fields?

Comment: I just scripted a solution to copy the same table 100 times, haha. I still iterated over every table though.

Comment: :) Oh I see! Also, this might be a question for a different post but I never understood why (especially noticed that in GIS) would people use "with..as"? I read many stackoverflow posts but I don't seems to get it. Does the syntax similar to writing a try/catch block?

Comment: Using "with...as" disposes of the object after you are done with it. In ArcGIS, not disposing stuff sometimes creates issues dealing with memory management. Using "with...as" provides a nice clean way to use a resource and automatically get rid/release it when you are done with it. It's a cleaner method than a try/finally block: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm